# Can validate an array of date[] but not process it?

Tags: php, validation

I have a problem with this now, on the end of my mydate I have put [] so I can have an array to process and on the other page, I have process.php.

In the process.php, I have

```
foreach($_POST["mydate"] as $mydate ){     
        if($mydate != ''){
         Date processed...etc etc....
   }
```

If I put the [], it will store it but wont validate and if I dont put [], it will validate but not post?

Any thoughts?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function checkdate(input){
    var validformat=/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/ //Basic check for format validity
    var returnval=false
    if (!validformat.test(input.value))
    alert("Invalid Date Format. Please correct and submit again.")
    else{ //Detailed check for valid date ranges
    var monthfield=input.value.split("/")[0]
    var dayfield=input.value.split("/")[1]
    var yearfield=input.value.split("/")[2]
    var dayobj = new Date(yearfield, monthfield-1, dayfield)
    if ((dayobj.getMonth()+1!=monthfield)||(dayobj.getDate()!=dayfield)||(dayobj.getFullYear()!=yearfield))
    alert("Invalid Day, Month, or Year range detected. Please correct and submit again.")
    else
    returnval=true
    }
    if (returnval==false) input.select()
    return returnval
    }
    function CheckDates(inputs)
{
    var i, len;
    if (inputs.length) {
        len = inputs.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (!checkdate(inputs[i])) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return checkdate(inputs);
}

    function add(tbl1) {
        var tbl = document.getElementById(tbl1);
        var rowCount = tbl.rows.length;
        var row = tbl.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = tbl.rows[1].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newCell = row.insertCell(i);
            newCell.innerHTML = tbl.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }
    </script>

    <form name "enter" action="enter.php" onSubmit="return Checkdate(this.mydate)" method="post">
    <table id="day" border="1">
    <tr><b>Valid date format:</b><br></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <input type="text" name="mydate" />
    </table><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="add('day')"/>
    </form>
```

EDITTED
removed the space but still doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this construction:

```
foreach ($_POST["mydate"] as $mydate ) {     
    if(!empty($mydate) && !is_null($mydate)) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Make print_r($_POST) with <input name="mydate[]" />
Try to use
<input name="form[mydate]" /> and <?php foreach $_POST['form'] ?> and <?php if (!empty($_POST['form']['mydate'])) { } ?>
Show you process function

Answer (score 2):

If there are more than one of the input field, the name must be `mydate[]` so they are placed in an array, and in your processing code you have an extra space...  `$_POST['mydate ']` won't work it must be `$_POST['mydate']`

edit: this line `<input type="text" name="mydate" />` must be `<input type="text" name="mydate[]" />`